# Why can't I use this palindrome function when using an STL list?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, palindrome, auto

I made a palindrome function that allows me to use any container type, and it worked for string, vector, and deque but when I made an STL list and tried running the code, but I get the error bellow and I couldn't figure out what that means and what to do.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2676   binary '-': 'std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator homework4   C:\...\Source.cpp   9   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3536   'itr1': cannot be used before it is initialized homework4   C:\...\Source.cpp   9   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2676   binary '<': 'std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator homework4   C:\...\Source.cpp   9   
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2100   illegal indirection homework4   C:\...\Source.cpp   10
```

[Visual studio error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpYRW.png)

Below the code I ran.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
#include<deque>
using namespace std;

template <typename Container>
bool palindrome(const Container& s) {
    for (auto itr = s.begin(), itr1 = s.end() - 1; itr < itr1; itr++, itr1--) {
        if (*itr != *itr1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void main() {
    const string word1{ "racecar" };
    const vector<char> word2{ 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a' };
    const deque<int> word3{ 83, 84, 65, 84, 83 };
    const list<int> word4{ 83, 84, 65, 84, 83 };
    word4.end();

    cout << palindrome< string >(word1) << endl;
    cout << palindrome< vector<char> >(word2) << endl;
    cout << palindrome< deque<int> >(word3) << endl;
    cout << palindrome< list<int> >(word4) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Replace `s.end() - 1` with `std::prev(s.end())`. The former requires a random-access iterator, which list iterator is not.

Comment: use a reverse iterator for the second case with `s.rbegin()` and `s.rend()`

Comment: In addition, in the future, use `std::next`, `std::advance`, `std::distance`, etc. if you need to do things like this in a generic fashion.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik There will also be a problem with `itr < itr1` for the list iterator, as the `<` operator is also not defined for such.

Comment: @AdrianMole True. Would need something like `itr != itr1 && itr != std::next(itr1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard container std::list has bidirectional iterators. The operator - used in this expression

```
itr1 = s.end() - 1
```

is defined for random access iterators. You could use instead the standard function `std::prev` declared in the header `<iterator>` like

```
itr1 = std::prev( s.end() )
```

However in any case the function is invalid because in general the user of the function can pass an empty container. In this case the expression `std::prev( s.end() )` has undefined behavior.

And the operator < is not defined for bidirectional iterators. So this expression

```
itr < itr1
```

also may not be used in the function.

Moreover the function will not work with arrays because arrays do not have member functions like for example `begin()`.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Container>
bool palindrome( const Container &c ) 
{
    auto first = std::begin( c );
    auto last  = std::end( c );

    while ( first != last && first != --last && *first == *last ) ++first;      

    return first == last;
}

int main() 
{
    const std::string word1{ "racecar" };
    const std::vector<char> word2{ 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a' };
    const std::deque<int> word3{ 83, 84, 65, 84, 83 };
    const std::list<int> word4{ 83, 84, 65, 84, 83 };
    const char word5[] =  { 83, 84, 65, 84, 83 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindrome( word1 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindrome( word2 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindrome( word3 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindrome( word4 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindrome( word5 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
true
true
true
true
```

If you want you can specialize the function for random access iterators.

Comment: Very clever loop condition! Probably needs specialization for `const char *` converting to `std::string` or `std::string_view`